# HInclude Caching problem on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, caching

I've been using HInclude (http://www.mnot.net/javascript/hinclude/) for sometime now and its working great, but there is one problem though. The part of my site which is fetched using HInclude doesn't get refreshed everytime I hit the back button in Internet Exploer (6.x + and 7.0 also). It works fine on other browsers. I've tried setting the cache-control and pragma controls in header to "no-Cache". but even that is not working. I want HInclude to pick up new content everytime a user clicks back button or re-visits a page with hx content on it. How do I do that?

Comment: FYI, if this is still an issue for you:
HInclude is now on github, and I've entered this as an issue there; see https://github.com/mnot/hinclude/issues/4 . 
  
From memory, this may be a fundamental limitation of those IE versions, but I'll have a closer look once I'm home from holiday.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to put some random string in the end of your JS link ?

Answer (score 0):

A full traffic capture would be useful to see exactly what your server is sending. Having said that, the IE team [did work in IE9](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx) to help ensure that hitting the Back button wouldn't hit the server, as allowed by RFC2616 and as implemented in other browsers.

Prior to IE9, the back behavior was pretty screwy/buggy and whether the server got hit could depend on whether the page had explicit caching directives and what the user's IE cache settings were (see midway through this [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). In practice, the server was hit much more often than it should have been (which is, of course, never).

If I recall correctly, I think one of the pre-IE9 bugs was to that if the caching headers contained must-revalidate, the client wouldn't pull the file from cache.

-Eric